# Glyph origins of 倒 (fall, collapse)

Tags: glyph-origin

Can anyone tell me the glyph origins for 倒 ?
I searched for it in one of the books but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

「倒」 (Mandarin: **dǎo**, **dào**; *to collapse/fall over*, *upside-down/inverted*) is comprised of semantic 「人・亻」 (*person*, "person falling over") and phonetic 「到」 (**dào**).

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://hanziyuan.net):

倒
Character decomposition 字形分解 [?]:
Compound 倒
from person-left-ren 亻人 rén and
phonetic arrive-dao 到 dào.

到
Character decomposition 字形分解 [?]:
Compound 到
from arrow-arrive-zhi 至 zhì and
phonetic knife-dao 刂刀 dāo.

至
Character decomposition 字形分解 [?]:
Component 至
from arrow-shi 矢 shǐ and
(rem+ 一 yī ground).
(name- arrow-arrive-zhi 至 zhì)

I have also read that 至 represents a bird swooping down to the ground. I'm sure our Chinese friends here have a very accurate etymology!

They say that 到 is just phonetic, but in 人 alone there is no sense of 'down'. I think some meaning of ‘down’ must derive from 至。

Ever noticed how 倒 sounds like 'down'? But down comes from Old English dun (= hill, rhymes with moon), which is exactly how the Scottish say 'down'!

I love to look for language links!

Comment: "They say that 到 is just phonetic, but in 人 alone there is no sense of 'down'. I think some meaning of ‘down’ must derive from 至。" - A semantic component rarely carries the full meaning of a character - usually it's just a hint as to its full meaning. For example, 运 doesn't mean walk, even though its semantic component is 走之旁. Meanwhile, it would be very rare for a part of the meaning to come from a part of the _phonetic_ component.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

[image]

[image]

倒 == 亻+ 到 == 亻+ 至 + 刂 （morphed from 人）, two human going backwards against each other